# Printing emoji with wprintf() on windows

Tags: c, windows, gcc, printf

```c
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    wprintf(L"٩(◕‿◕｡)۶\n");
    wprintf(L"\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The code above works perfectly on linux exactly as expected:

```
$ ./a.out
٩(◕‿◕｡)۶
```

but completely breaks on windows:

```
PS> ./a.exe
()
```

why does this happen?
How do I then, print emojis on windows?

Im using powershell with gcc 9.2.0 on windows and WSL with gcc 9.3.0 on powershell for linux.